# about creating a shared memory and provide the communication between parent/child process

Tags: c, process, ipc, shared-memory

hi there i'm trying to implement an example of using shared memory between child and parent process. The aim is child process have to calculate a fibonacci serie with a given size as an input from user and write every number as an element of an array. After that process will printout this array. The issue is if i create this memory segment and attach it before `fork()` operation it works fine, after i made `fork()` operation child process can reach that memory segment and generate the array properly and finally parent can printout the array after child finishes its job. the code is like this;

```
create memory segment
attach memory segment
initialize the array elements to zero
fork()
if(pid==0)// Child Process
call the child function and send the pointer of a structure which includes the array and array size
return to parent and printout the array properly
```

this is first example i implemented. However, i'm trying to use an another way as you can see the full code below;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SEQUENCE 10

typedef struct {

long fib_sequence[MAX_SEQUENCE];
int sequence_size;

} shared_data;

void child_func(shared_data* dataPtr);

void main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    int shmID,size,status,i;
    shared_data* dataPtr;
    pid_t pid;

            if((pid=fork())<0){
                printf("Error while fork()\n");
                exit(0);
            }

            else if(pid>0){ // Parent Process

                if((shmID = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, MAX_SEQUENCE*sizeof(long), IPC_CREAT | 0666))<0){
                    printf("Allocation process was unsuccesfull\n");
                    exit(0);
                }

                dataPtr = (shared_data*) shmat(shmID,NULL,0);

                for(i=0; i<MAX_SEQUENCE; i++)
                    dataPtr->fib_sequence[i]==0;

                dataPtr->sequence_size = atoi(argv[1]);

                if((dataPtr->sequence_size) < 0){
                    printf("You entered an invalid(negative) size number\n");
                    exit(0);
                }

                else if((dataPtr->sequence_size) > MAX_SEQUENCE){
                    printf("Please enter a value less than MAX_VALUE\n");
                    exit(0);
                }

                wait(status); // Wait untill child finishes its job

                for(i=0; i<dataPtr->sequence_size; i++)
                    printf("%ld ", dataPtr->fib_sequence[i]);

                printf("\n");
                shmdt((void *) dataPtr);
                shmctl(shmID,IPC_RMID,NULL);
            }

            else{ // Child Process
                child_func(dataPtr);
                exit(0);
                }
} 

void child_func(shared_data* dataPtr){

    int index;

    printf("I am in Child Process\n");
    printf("Size of array %d\n", dataPtr->sequence_size);

    dataPtr->fib_sequence[0];

    if((dataPtr->sequence_size) > 0){

        dataPtr->fib_sequence[1]=1;

        for(index=2; index < dataPtr->sequence_size; index++)
            dataPtr->fib_sequence[index] = dataPtr->fib_sequence[index-1] + dataPtr->fib_sequence[index-2];

    }

}
```

when i run the second example in when it enters in the child process it prints meaningless value of `dataPtr->fib_sequence`. i am curious about a few questions which are;

- In the second example why it prints wrong value of dataPtr->size in child
- In the first example can we admit that we do create and attach memory segment in parent process cause we are doing this stuff before `fork()` operation

Comment: If the shared memory pointer is not setup before the child process is forked, what do you expect it to be referencing upon entering child_func()?

Comment: but if i setup after `fork()` in parent, shouldn't be child take the same image of memory which parent uses.

Comment: The child process gets a snapshot of the parent memory pages, but after the fork it owns them, and the parent has its own. Look at the way your setup worked before changes. All the shmem setup was prior to the fork.